# How do I return "the rest of line" when data is stored in a row of a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
SELECT  definition 
FROM    sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition like '@noreturns'
```

This lists all of the objects that contain the string - however, I need to return the rest of the line of the object (for example, the rest of the line in the SP that contains that string in its definition)
But this is a table, so how would I return just the rest of the line and not the entire row (which in this case means the REST of the definition)??
Thank you

Comment: For example, a sample output would be: "@noreturns) + 29 + LTRIM(@Bay) + @RTRIM(@Join)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.syscomments` table for this.

```
select OBJECT_NAME(id), 
       text AllText, 
       SUBSTRING(text, CHARINDEX('MESAJ_LINK',text), CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),text,CHARINDEX('MESAJ_LINK',text)+1)) RestOfTheText
from 
      sys.syscomments 
where text like '%@noreturns%'
```

Comment: `sys.syscomments` is getting a whole object in one line, I think the OP needs a separated lines, so `sp_helptext ` is the correct approach as explained in my answer.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader if procedures writes well formatted you would be right. I mean write your dummy proc on same line and test it. And you dont make any search on the procedures. You have to know the procedure name.

Comment: It has the same inherent problem as I described in the question: it just gives everything until the end, because a row in a table does not have the concept of "line"

Answer (score 0):

Insert the output from `sp_helptext` to temp table as next approach:-

```
insert into #tableName
exec sp_helptext 'Object_Name'
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create procedure usp_DummyProc
@param1 int,
@param2 int
as
Begin
    select @param1 + @param2 as Result
    print 'This is dummy porcedure'
End
go

Create table #temp (Line varchar(2000))

insert into #temp
exec sp_helptext 'usp_DummyProc'

/* The Target is selecting the line that contains `print` word, 
so simply use the simple `select` with `where` */

select * from #temp
where Line like '%Print%'
```

Result:-

```
print 'This is dummy porcedure'
```

Comment: if procedures writes well formatted you would be right. I mean write your dummy proc on same line and test it. And you dont make any search on the procedures. You have to know the procedure exact  name.